# PHP AJAX always returning the same result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I'm trying to check if the email is already in use (for a password reset). So I have my JS

```
//Check if email exists
$(document).ready(function() {
//listens for typing on the desired field
$("#email").keyup(function() {
    //gets the value of the field
    var email = $("#email").val(); 

    //here is where you send the desired data to the PHP file using ajax
    $.post("../classes/check.php", {email:email},
        function(result) {
            if(result == 1) {
                //Email available
                console.log("Good");
            }
            else {
                //the email is not available
                console.log("Bad");
            }
        });
});
});
```

And then my PHP

```
<?php
//Include DB
include_once '../db.php';

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    //Get data
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
else{
    header('Location: /');
}
//Send requst to DB
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    //Email found
    echo 1;
}
else{
    //Email not found
    echo 0;
}
```

So I start off by making sure there's a recording in my DB. Which there is, so I enter it. Now I go over to the console and all I get is `Bad`, which means that the email is **not** found, but it's in the database. So I'd assume all it returns is `0`. Any ideas? Could it be an error in my code?

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab in the console to see what response is actually coming back from the server?

Comment: Have you tried logging out the `result`, what did it contain? Also, echoing numbers like that is not a good idea, neither is using weak equality to compare these results.

Comment: Don't use `htmlspecialchars` when storing data into the database. That should only be used when displaying data in an HTML page.

Comment: Yeah, all it returns is `0` @Barmar

Comment: You're sending the AJAX on *every* keyup and the e-mail will not be good until all the characters have been entered.

Comment: I understand. But how would that affect it? I entered all the characters and see the request, but it's the same result all the way through @JayBlanchard

Comment: You are trying to check the email address on every keyup?  That is certainly a nice way for an attacker to be able to build a nice dictionary of all possible email combinations on your site.

Comment: @MikeBrant Maybe this is the beginning of an auto-complete facility, it's just a WIP.

Comment: @MikeBrant Even if he doesn't, the attacker can just write a script of his own that tries every combination. He's not going to use the UI to do it.

Comment: So what would you suggest @MikeBrant

Comment: There's a warning in the PDO documentation that `rowCount` might not work after `SELECT`. Instead, use `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count` and fetch the value of `$row['count']`

Comment: Are you watching the request / response in the browser's console @user302975?

Comment: Yes I am. The console is all the same no matter what, and I see the requests going out @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDO documentation warns that `rowCount` might not work with all drivers. A more reliable and efficient way to do it is:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE email = :email");
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row['count'] > 0) {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

Another thing to try:

```
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
```

because sometimes there's extra whitespace in theinput field.

Comment: Nope, still tossing the same issue.

Comment: Try trimming the input

Comment: Still no change. I also tried a different browser to get the cache issue out of the way. Same things going on :(

Comment: Then I think you're wrong about the email being in the database. I can't see any reason for this to fail.

Comment: I just fixed a typo in my SQL (`cont` => `count`). Could that have been the problem?

Comment: You missed the closing bracket to the `if`.